# UIKeyBoard Return Button UIReturnKeyDone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ipad, uikeyboard

```
textfield.returnKeyTYpe = UIReturnKeyDone
```

So the above makes my Return button on the keyboard to say Done. I have seen Apps with Blue color button on the UIKeyBoard. Is that simple enough to do? How do I change the background color of the Return key?

Answer (score 4):

The Return key only turns blue if it has a type other than `UIReturnKeyDefault` *and* is enabled.  To make sure it gets enabled, you can set `textfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES`.

Comment: ok i tried that didn't work. the blue button i have seen is on iPhone apps. is it different for iPad? I am using SDK 3.2 Beta 5.

Comment: I'm not sure that the iPad highlights the Return key in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

```
textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain you can, and if you can I think that you might need to either roll your own keyboard or use undocumented methods. Alternatively, you could draw your own view over the button and simply make it transparent to user touches. [This article](http://unsolicitedfeedback.com/?p=44) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The return key background color turns AUTOMATICALLY into blue as soon as the user enters code  for e.g. into a `UITextField`.

Comment: for me not work. last version of iOS and Xcode. (type = .next)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in **Swift** that does the job:

```
extension ViewController {

func subviewsOfView(view : UIView, withType type:NSString) -> NSArray {
    let prefix = NSString(format: "<%@",type) as String
    let subViewsArray = NSMutableArray()
    for subview in view.subviews {
        let tempArray = subviewsOfView(subview, withType: type)
        for view in tempArray {
            subViewsArray.addObject(view)
        }
    }
    if view.description.hasPrefix(prefix) {
        subViewsArray.addObject(view)
    }
    return NSArray(array: subViewsArray)
}

func addColorToUIKeyboardButton() {
    for keyboardWindow in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
        for keyboard in keyboardWindow.subviews {
            for view in self.subviewsOfView(keyboard, withType: "UIKBKeyplaneView") {
                let newView = UIView(frame: (self.subviewsOfView(keyboard, withType: "UIKBKeyView").lastObject as! UIView).frame)
                newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x + 2, newView.frame.origin.y + 1, newView.frame.size.width - 4, newView.frame.size.height - 3)
                newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //Or whatever color you want
                newView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
                view.insertSubview(newView, belowSubview: self.subviewsOfView(keyboard, withType: "UIKBKeyView").lastObject as! UIView)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Note**: Make sure the keyboard is visible before you call *addColorToUIKeyboardButton()*