# highlight the 'return' button on the iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, return, highlight

I am trying to find a way to highlight the return button on the standard ios keyboard, but i do not find any documentation.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank very much for answers.

Comment: Next time, before you post, remember that signatures are not allowed, according to the FAQ, and please check over your post for spelling & grammatical errors.

Comment: the official apple documentation shows the 'Go' buttonhighlighted (http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3).
how is this done?

Comment: seems like nobody knows, huh????

Comment: I started a bounty for you, hopefully that draws some attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIKeyBoard Return Button UIReturnKeyDone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480788/uikeyboard-return-button-uireturnkeydone)

Answer (score 5):

The return button cannot be highlighted, the highlighted state exists for different values of `UIReturnKeyType`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

The blue highlight appears on all of these except for `UIReturnKeyDefault` (which incidentally is the one that says "Return").

You can set the `UIReturnKeyType` on any text input control that conforms to `UITextInputTraits` (e.g. `UITextField`, `UITextView`) `[id <UITextInputTraits> returnKeyType]`.

Answer (score 0):

I case yo want to custom your textView a little more, I found an example about [how to add a custom button to the keyboard](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html). That code is dated on March, 2008 and I couldn't make it work on iOS5, but you can get the idea:

```
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {

    //The UIWindow that contains the keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow;

    //Because we cant get access to the UIKeyboard throught the SDK we will just use UIView. 
    //UIKeyboard is a subclass of UIView anyways
    UIView* keyboard;

    //Check each window in our application
    for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
    {
        //Get a reference of the current window
        tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];

        //Get a reference of the current view 
        for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
        {
            keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"(lessThen)UIKeyboard"] == YES)
            {
                //Keyboard is now a UIView reference to the UIKeyboard we want. From here we can add a subview
                //to th keyboard like a new button
                dot = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                dot.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
                [dot setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"period.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [dot setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"period2.gif"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [keyboard addSubview:dot];
                [dot addTarget:self action:@selector(addDot:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```